# Difficulty in shading outer and inner part of the curve

Tags: graph, jsxgraph

I need to graph the function y=4/x in jsx graphing and shade both the region inner part and out part of the curve.

Comment: So, what have you done so far?

Comment: See the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsxgraph/PckP08AuzUA